# how to refer outputfield from derivedfield in pmml

Tags: sas, pmml

I have derivedfields in my pmml I want to use them as outputfields. So I want to refer outputfield from derivedfield. But sas application throw an error. Error is :

> ERROR: Variable Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID is not defined.

How can I set outputfield from derived field?
Here is my pmml which doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

  <PMML version="4.2"

   xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2"

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <Header copyright="Copyright(c) 2002 SAS Institute Inc., Cary, NC, USA. All Rights Reserved.">

    <Application name="SAS(r)" version="9.4"/>

    <Timestamp>2016-06-23 15:36:04</Timestamp>

    </Header>

    <DataDictionary numberOfFields="26">

      <DataField name="CH_INT_FLG_CRR" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>

      <DataField name="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5" optype="categorical" dataType="string"/>

      <DataField name="TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="double"/>

    </DataDictionary>

    <TransformationDictionary>

    </TransformationDictionary>

    <RegressionModel functionName="classification" targetFieldName="TARGET_NUM" normalizationMethod="logit">

      <MiningSchema>

        <MiningField name="CH_INT_FLG_CRR" usageType="active" optype="continuous"/>

        <MiningField name="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5" usageType="active" optype="categorical"/>

        <MiningField name="TARGET_NUM" usageType="target" optype="categorical"/>

      </MiningSchema>

      <Output>

        <OutputField name="I_TARGET_NUM" displayName="Into: TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="string" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="predictedValue"/>

        <OutputField name="U_TARGET_NUM" displayName="Unnormalized Into: TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="string" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="predictedDisplayValue"/>

        <OutputField name="P_TARGET_NUM1" displayName="Predicted: TARGET_NUM=1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="probability" value="1"/>

        <OutputField name="P_TARGET_NUM0" displayName="Predicted: TARGET_NUM=0" optype="continuous" dataType="double" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="probability" value="0"/>


                <OutputField name="out_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
        <FieldRef field="Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID"/>
    </OutputField>

    <OutputField name="out_2" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
        <FieldRef field="Z_CH_INT_FLG_CRR"/>
    </OutputField>


      </Output>

      <Targets>

        <Target field="TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical">

          <TargetValue value="1" displayValue="1" priorProbability="0.5000049143"/>

          <TargetValue value="0" displayValue="0" priorProbability="0.4999950857"/>

        </Target>

      </Targets>

      <LocalTransformations>

      <DerivedField name="Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID" displayName="Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID" optype="continuous" dataType="double" >
        <MapValues  outputColumn="return" defaultValue="99.9">
        <FieldColumnPair  column="condition" field="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5"/>
        <InlineTable>
        <row>
        <condition>9999</condition>
        <return>-0.0992686543837357</return>
        </row>
        <row>
        <condition>7130</condition>
        <return>-0.010300374749499</return>
        </row>
        </InlineTable>
        </MapValues>
        </DerivedField>


        <DerivedField name="Z_CH_INT_FLG_CRR" displayName="Z_CH_INT_FLG_CRR" optype="continuous" dataType="double">

            <Discretize field="CH_INT_FLG_CRR" >

                <DiscretizeBin binValue="0.0154213834">

                    <Interval closure="openOpen" rightMargin="0"/>

                </DiscretizeBin>

                <DiscretizeBin binValue="-0.025845983">

                    <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0"/>

                </DiscretizeBin>

                <DiscretizeBin binValue="0.0154213834">

                    <Interval closure="openOpen" leftMargin="0"/>

                </DiscretizeBin>

            </Discretize> 

        </DerivedField>

      </LocalTransformations>

      <RegressionTable intercept="0.0203226371" targetCategory="1">

        <NumericPredictor name="Z_CH_INT_FLG_CRR" coefficient="7.5086455767" />

        <NumericPredictor name="Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID" coefficient="3.2" />


      </RegressionTable>

      <RegressionTable intercept="0" targetCategory="0"/>

    </RegressionModel>

  </PMML>
```

If I use datadictionary columns instead of derived fields, it works perfectly.

For example If I convert

```
    <OutputField name="out_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
        <FieldRef field="Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID"/>
    </OutputField>

    <OutputField name="out_2" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
        <FieldRef field="Z_CH_INT_FLG_CRR"/>
    </OutputField>
```

to

```
<OutputField name="out_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
    <FieldRef field="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5"/>
</OutputField>

<OutputField name="out_2" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
    <FieldRef field="CH_INT_FLG_CRR"/>
</OutputField>
```

it works. Because in this case, I refer outputfield from datadictionary columns. But actually I need to use derivedfields in outputfields. How can I refer outputfields from derivedfields?

Comment: any idea ? @user1808924

Comment: You should specify what error you are receiving.

Comment: you are right. I updated my question. @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your derived fields from `LocalTransformations` (ie. local scope) to `TransformationDictionary` (ie. global scope).

PMML 4.2 does not permit referencing local derived fields from output fields. The "logic" is that you cannot reference a field before it has been seen by the PMML parser. In you example, `OutputField@name=out_1` element occurs before `DerivedField@name=Z_DD_OCCUPATION_ID` element.

PMML 4.3 relaxed this rule. See http://mantis.dmg.org/view.php?id=142 for details.